# Can't access review queue dropdown since appearance of "NEW" with salary calculator

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

Any attempt to click on the button in the top-bar results in a page reload, thus effectively preventing me from accessing the review queues by this dropdown.

[image]

It is fine on Meta, but not on main site. It is happening only since the introduction of the "NEW" button featuring the salary calculator, so I suppose it is related.

I must say that on meta, no review queue is accessible to me, so it might explain a behavior difference as well.

Comment: Just tried again... the "NEW" button is not there anymore, and I can access the dropdown queues menu as usual.

Comment: I'm guessing they temporarily rolled back to previous version while they work out the bugs

Comment: yep, I think so too. Should I delete my post ?

Comment: No, it's still potentially valid.

Comment: This has been fixed with the latest build and release of the [new feature notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification).