# How is Stack Overflow "new"?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm very confused by the current title of Stack Overflow. I first noticed SO being called "new" around the time of the redesign. I figured that was because SO was relaunching or something along those lines. Even so it seemed like a stretch considering it's been around for a decade.

And yet even now SO is claiming to be new. Why?

[image]
[image]

---

Sorry, I didn't realize it was a button. In my defence it looks a lot like the meta tag.

Comment: Did you click that burton?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification

Comment: Wait... that is a button? Honestly I thought it was a way of indicating all this redesign going on

Comment: Now 100% more welcoming!

Comment: It's the newest hand-holding tutorial site on the internet.

Comment: Just poor design choices. Plenty of other place on the UI that has room for a "button" like that, where it sits all by itself.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the "new" you'll see that it's a link.

Click on it and it will show you what's new with Stack Overflow. New features, a new blog post, or in this case (Sept 2018) the salary survey.

Comment: Ah thank you! That really wasn't obviously. Especially as it looks like the meta logo.

Comment: English has a word for "What's new" that conveniently fits on widgets, namely *News*.  Would you suggest the change to the appropriate people?

Comment: Oh the irony. The button he asked about was the answer to his very question. :D

Comment: I don't see it. Was it removed already, or do I see a different design for some reason? :)

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt Too late! Not new (or news) any more... :)

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt Try looking at the homepage from an incognito window.

Comment: The button is still there for me without any news to announce. It only opens a new window with same content. The mechanism to indicate "no news" seems to be broken somehow.