# Usage of the New Feature Notification

Tags: discussion, top-bar

[Some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification), after strongly negative feedback from the community,  we were told that

> The “new feature” notification (from here on referred to as NFN) is telling you about new features or significant future improvements. These features could be for Q&A, Jobs, Channels or some future product area. This is NOT a feature to push users who aren’t interested in Jobs to Jobs.

I honestly had completely forgotten about that button up until a couple of days ago when the salary calculator was updated. Should we take it as that button is solely meant for Jobs ads or that nothing has been done in the past year?
For example, why wasn't it used for the Code of Conduct if the button supposedly reaches so much more people?

Comment: Maybe they forgot that they added the feature. Much like the rest of us ;)

Comment: I don't mind as long as they are not using that button too much. Plus you can dismiss the button with one click (and forget about it).

Comment: Or `@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") { .unread-feature-notice{display:none !Important;} }` it away (for Stylus addon)

Comment: This _is_ not a feature to push users who aren’t interested in Jobs to Jobs... It's a feature to indiscriminately advertise Jobs stuff to everyone who will click there regardless of whether they are interested or not. See? They don't discriminate, they're _inclusive_. They don't _lie_ at all. These features _could_ be for Q&A, Jobs, Channels or some future product area; it's just that they _will_ only be used to "feature" Jobs ads.

Comment: Still think it should go in the [New & Shiny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356862/57475) section I proposed way back when.

Answer (score 3):

We have a variety of things we can use to promote new features and/or changes on the site. For the Code of Conduct we used an announcement banner. It wasn't really a "new feature" per se. So that seemed appropriate. Also, it was a change that potentially impacts everyone who comes to the site, so we wanted to make sure everyone saw it.

The "new feature" notification is more focused. As such it won't be used frequently. We used it twice for the salary calculator and once for Teams. We have some upcoming features that we would use it for as well. The funny thing is that many of our "new features" get tested before they release so they don't feel so new to us anymore. We have to remember that isn't the case for many of you.

Also, other changes are focused on in featured meta posts and/or blog posts. We try to use the right channel for the message. One thing we are looking into is creating a single source of truth (aka changelog) for all changes (significant bug fixes, updates, new features, etc).

Comment: Is the "New feature" notification tool SE-wide, or is it specific to SO?

Comment: @NicolBolas I haven't seen it on other SE sites... I think it is for just SO

Comment: So far it has only been used for things that have no relevance to Q&A, so it is establishing itself as an "Irrelevant Jobs Ads" button instead of a "New Feature Notification". If you had put the announcement in a meta post and featured it, I would have known at a glance that I had absolutely no interest. Behind the NFN button, you're saying "here's a shiny new surprise for you to unwrap by clicking this shiny button"  then I have to click on the button only to be disappointed by the reveal. If I don't take the click-bait, then there's a shiny button sitting at the top of the page tempting me.

Comment: Just adblock it. The chances of it being used for something that isn't already announced by a featured meta post or blog are slim. If you're a regular meta user, it's likely this featured button won't be of use to you, it's for the other people who aren't regular meta users.